# Cleanest way to avoid accessng an array out of bounds?

Tags: c++

Say I have a 5x5 2D Array. For a given position in the array, I need to check if the adjacent positions contains a certain value. How do I handle elements that are on the edge of the array?

For example, my immediate thought to handle something like this would be;

```
if(array[i-1][j] != 'A' && array[i][j-1] != 'A' && array[i+1][j] != 'A' && array[i][j+1] != 'A')
```

but given any element where i or j is 0/4, one (or two) of those statements will attempt to check something that is out of bounds of the dimension of the array. Is there a clean way to do this without nesting a bunch of if statements to check if the element is at the edge?

Comment: One possibility is to use a 7x7 array and fill it with a sentry value along the fringes.

Comment: Unfortunately, the array is already defined and used in a lot of different areas of the larger program. Changing the size is not an option

Comment: The immediate question is how do you want the out of bounds values to be treated? Does `array[-1][0]` count as a 'A' or not?

Comment: I preferably just want to avoid accessing the out of bounds values to avoid any errors that may cause. But yes, technically anything out of bounds would be counted as A as I only want to check if the element is not surrounded by A.

Comment: For me, excluding aesthetics, the answer is: just write the boundary-checking code explicitely. `if(x<0) return false; if(x>4)return false; if(y<0)...`. A few TRIVIAL lines of code more, but maintenance and transparency gets a boost. But your "goodness" criteria may be different. I started thinking about what you asked for, and I ended up judging what is nice and what is not nice for MY eyes. This code feels good, that one feels less.. and this means, it's an opinion-based question, with no really "best" answer, as the answer shifts from person to person and over time as we grow in experience.

Answer (score 1):

You can use boolean logic, and short circuit evaluation

```
if ((i == 0 || array[i-1][j] != 'A') &&
    (j == 0 || array[i][j-1] != 'A') &&
    (i == 4 || array[i+1][j] != 'A') &&
    (j == 4 || array[i][j+1] != 'A'))
{
    ...
}
```

I'm assuming that you want to consider `array[-1][j] != 'A'` etc as true. If not then the expression would change.

Comment: Thank you. This looks like it'll work for what I need. I'll give it a shot.

Answer (score 1):

This is a common problem in image processing. As molbdnilo notes in the comments, a common solution is to add some padding; since you use a 3x3 neighborhood you need to add just a single pixel on all sides.

Another solution that's sometimes used is to mirror accesses beyond the image bound. That is to say, if `x>bound` you use `(2*bound-x)` instead, and the same for y. Alternatively, you can use `if (x>bound) x=bound`. A common factor here is that you limit the number of if-statements by handling x and y separately.

Comment: Also worth noting that "adding a padding" means that you must choose an either "safe" or "n/a" value, because the effects of that value may "flow" into output as if it was the real data. In terms of image processing, for example, if you're blurring a white image and add a (0,0,0,0) padding (virtually in the algo by boundary conditions, or really in the data, whatever), the blackness will spoil the bounds of the image, the more passes of algorithm, the more damage applied. and sometimes you have such an algorithm that you really don't know what a "safe" value could be!

Comment: @quetzalcoatl: Correct, the choice may vary between operations. For blurring the mirroring makes more sense, but for edge detection it might be better to use the `if (x>bound) x=bound` trick.

Answer (score 0):

You can try splitting the algorithm in two parts:

- first do all the cases in the 3x3 array inside the 5x5 which doesn't have the edge cases
- finish up with all the remaining edges

In each situation you know in what condition you are, so you can minimise ìf` checks

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a clean way to do this without nesting a bunch of if statements to check if ...

Yes. That is called NOT nesting.
Focus on the `checking` part, and notice that you don't need nesting.
For any part of the test to be done, a partial result may define the total outcome, and you can use it to break the code into parts.

Instead of

```
// using short-cut evaluation to build a HUGE if
if(x > 0 && y > 0 && data[x][y-1] != 'A' ...)
{
   do something1;
   do something2;
}
```

or

```
// using nesting to guarantee some conditions "from now onwards"
if(x > 0 && y > 0)
{
    do something1;
    if(data[x][y-1] != 'A' ...)
        do something2;
}
```

just write

```
bool Check1(...)
{
    if(x < 0) return false; // A*
    if(y < 0) return false;
    ...

    return true;
}

bool Check2(...)
{
    if(data[x][y-1] != 'A') return false; // A*
    ...

    return true;
}
```

and at the original place

```
bool sidesOk = Ćheck1(....);
bool neighboursOk = Ćheck2(....);

// first case
if(sidesOk && neighboursOk)
{
   do something1;
   do something2;
}

// second case
if(sidesOk)
   do something1;

if(sidesOk && neighboursOk)
   do something2;

// or even - depending on your algorithm
if(!sidesOk)
   return;
```

But then, it's down to aesthetics and your personal preferences. Both this and your code works. There might be minor performance differences (measure it if you need!) but the overall logic and the result are the same.

*Notabene - A* - note that there are some "good coding rules" that discourage constructing code that have multiple return paths, and that promote a "single function single return" rule. As if tracing when/where the function exists is a hard thing. If you ever heard this rule, forget it, and your life will be easier. This rule was invented when we were writing **assembly** by hand and when the assembly was at pre-MacroAssembler stage, and contained no macros and no functions and you wrote function-like code manually by conditions and jumps. Adapting that rule to current tools and needs, it should say "keep branching and return paths easy to comprehend". And yes, the `if(x)return false` block is what the compiler would do when you are using short-cut evaluation `if(x&&y&&..)` "so why dont we keep it one-line already" - it's more important for the code to be easy for humans to read.*